# SQlite Pagination on ListView scrolling in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, pagination

I'm Stuck in implementing Pagination in Android.I need help to creating pagination with Sq-lite local database at the end of List-view Scrolling.I'm trying to add 10 items per page and increase the local page index up to 5 times on List view Scrolling at the end and append the next 10 Sq-lite data rows in List-view , but something is wrong with my code.Only 1 page size creating when I scrolling 2nd time page size does not increase by 1 and progress-bar is running contentiously . Can some one help me to solve this .

Here is my Code for ListView Scrolling.

```
listView.addFooterView(footer);
        // Implementing scroll refresh
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {
                //Log.e("Get position", "--firstItem:" + firstItem + "  visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount + "  totalItems:" + totalItems + "  pageCount:" + pageCount);
                int total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;

               Log.e("", "onScroll LocalPages=" + LocalPages);
                // Total array list i have so it
                if (pageCount < LocalPages) {

                    if (total == totalItems) {

                        // Execute some code after 8 seconds have passed
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                listView.addFooterView(footer);
                                OFFSET = pageCount * 10 ;
                                //Log.e("","After OFFSET pageCount =" + pageCount + "  OFFSET value ="+OFFSET);
                                List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions(OFFSET);
                                for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc)
                                {
                                    descArray.add(all_Post);
                                }
                                if(adapter != null)
                                {
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    listView.setSelection(totalItems);

                                    pageCount += 1;
                                    Log.e("","  pageCount =" + pageCount + " LocalPages="+LocalPages);

                                }
                            }
                        }, 8000);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("hide footer", "footer hide");
                    listView.removeFooterView(footer);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advanced .

Comment: no pagination needed at all: i have a table with 50000 rows and it just works ok, one thing: use a `[Simple]CursorAdapter`

Comment: But I want to implement pagination.

Comment: then write your custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override `getCount` and `getView` methods, it should be done with less then 10 lines of effective code as it is really an easy case

Comment: actually the base implementation takes 5 lines of code but it depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: I want to achieve if i scroll at the end of List View its showing progress bar 5 seconds  after that next 10 records to append to list then again scroll list view its again showing progress bar 5 seconds  after that again next 10 records append to list view . This process is run for up to page size. For that I'm using offset and limit query.

Comment: so as i said: make a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`: for a 5 seconds delay you would probably need to add another 5 lines of code

Comment: I'm trying since 5 days , still I'm not getting proper way solution.So what not interested

Comment: well, i posted two hints what to do with `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: ok, so i am posting this link only because you are fighting with that for a week now: http://pastebin.com/RPEyRAsk, next time see some tutorials on how to use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` when working with sqlite db

Comment: @pskink : Hi , Thanks for the help but I don't understand your tutorial . It is not possible of my way which is I post the above code.

Comment: I edited my code but that way my pageCount size is increases out of limit , it is not go to else condition after condition is satisfied .Can you see my edited post.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean: does my adapter "paginate" or not? (i mean if you scroll to the bottom, does it shows more items?)

Comment: But i don't have get all the data in adapter.So that's why I'm using LIMIT and OFFSET query.

Comment: what do you need LIMIT and OFFSET for?

Comment: Because i have 150000 data in sq-lite how can I populate all the data at time .

Comment: did you try my `SimpleCursorAdapter`? did you really run my code?

Comment: Yes i tried it , but not work. So removed it  from my project.its getting OutOfmemory error exception

Comment: just tested that with a table of 351456 (350k) rows and no "OutOfmemory" errors